# Error formatting Esper query

Tags: java, database, esper

I'm using (or trying to use) Esper to retrieve a specific class of object of which one of the methods returns a specific value. Here's the statement I'm setting now.

```
EsperEventConsumer consumer = new EsperEventConsumer();
consumer.setEsperStatement("select * from com.my.package.MyClass as test where test.getObject().getValue()='" + myValue + "'");
```

I know everything else works because when I do the following, everything works fine, except for the lack of filtering that is.

```
EsperEventConsumer consumer = new EsperEventConsumer();
consumer.setEsperStatement("select * from com.my.package.MyClass");
```

The statement is specifically thrown on "test.getObject()."

```
Caused by: com.espertech.esper.client.EPStatementException: Failed to solve 'getObject' to either an date-time or enumeration method, an event property or a method on the event underlying object [select * from com.my.package.MyClass as test where test.getObject().getValue()='dfe28df9-4f8e-4016-907d-d1852f6add49']
```

Thanks!

Comment: post the definition for your MyClass

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like MyClass doesn't have a method "getObject", provide the full code if still having trouble.